# DNP3 with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for a good `DNP3 library` for `.NET`/`VB` applications.

Any recommendations?

Thanks,

Comment: There's an open source C++ library here, with the actual Source code on Github (link part way down this page).  You could compile this code using Visual C++ Express, and make a DLL and call functions in that DLL from C#/VB.net. : http://code.google.com/p/dnp3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I could find with a Google search was [Trianble MicroWorks' .NET Protocol Components](http://www.trianglemicroworks.com/NET%20Page.htm).

It looks like they're not exactly on top of the latest technology (it lists itself as .NET framework 2.0 compatible), but I wasn't able to find anything else that looked terribly promising.

Answer (score 2):

The open-dnp3 project has recently added .NET bindings:

code.google.com/p/dnp3

Answer (score 2):

Automatak maintains a fork of the opendnp3 library with .NET bindings:

http://automatak.com/opendnp3/

We have heard from users that opendnp3 significantly outperforms the TMW library for large master integrations.

Opendnp3 is Apache-licensed (free-to-use), but commercial support is available if you get stuck.

Comment: Automatak's libraries are great.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to build the Automatak version of this library:
https://github.com/automatak/dnp3
and use the .NET bindings with C#, though they would work equally well with VB.

Answer (score 1):

OpenDNP3 from automak is available in Nuget, but you should install 32bit openssl application to able to load it.It installs two required .dll files.